# How to solve "For your messages security, System message app has been set as the default message app” issue on Oppo devices?

Tags: android, sms, default, oppo

I implemented an SMS app. Now I'm having trouble with Oppo devices because whenever a message is received, the system changes the default app to the built-in app and shows this message:

> For your messages security, System message app has been set as the default message app

I need to solve this issue programmatically as thousands of users will be using the app and I cannot let them change it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in a other thread on OPPO:

> Whatever settings you change for the messaging will not make any difference, the phone will always revert to the default app.

I took this up directly with OPPO and had the following response:

> We decided not to allow customer to set 3rd party applications as default message application, for security of the devices cannot be guaranteed. We also want to let you experience our built-in application and to be spared from the malfunction like virus, bug or etc.

Not the response I wanted or expected!

Possibly the phone has been set this way is because in China the government is granted access to all private communications as a way to preserve a permanent dictatorship? Thus Chinese brands may be knowingly spreading these settings in android devices around the world.

Comment: Sad and confused by this decision. Anyway, thank you so much for the answer. It’s good to know that I won’t waste more time trying to solve this.

Comment: Oppo, Vivo, OnePlus, MI, RedMi, Honor, Huwei, RealMe are not phones, These all are CHINESE VIRUSES